# Creating a custom keyboard on Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, viewcontroller

I'm quite new to iOS to if you could explain in detail that would be great:)

I'm trying to create a keyboard on the view itself. I have dragged 9 buttons onto a modal view labelled 1 through 9. A bit similar to the picture below.

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/seaec5/5]

My question is what is the best way to implement functionality. Do i really need to create 9 iboutlets and link them up to each button just so i can return its corresponding number? e.g. number 1 button is linked up to a number 1 iboutlet method so it can return 1?

Any help would be great thanks :)

Ryan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a common "Touch up inside "outlet function for all buttons... and Set different tags for each buttons.. for example

```
-(IBAction)btnKeyboardAction:(id)sender // common "Touch up inside" action for all four buttons
{
 UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender; //assuming that you have set tag for buttons

      if(btn.tag==1)
        {

          //Do any thing for button 1
         }
       else if (btn.tag==2)
        {
          returnView.text = @"Test";
          //Do any thing for button 2
         }
       else if (btn.tag==3)
        {
          //Do any thing for button 3
         }
        else
           {
             //Do any thing for button 4

            }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tag of button to get the value instead of linking each button to a different outlet. Use this tag inside your code to check the number tapped.